# Trying to display a popup gives "The Parent must be of type Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.PageHandler."

Tags: mvvm, popup, maui

Trying to follow this example to display a custom popup but using MVVM and Shell gives me the error in the title:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yM7opXlu-MU&ab_channel=GeraldVersluis

```
namespace MyPopupTest
{
    public partial class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            DisplayMyPopup();
        }

        private void DisplayMyPopup()
        {
            var popup = new MyPopup();
            Shell.Current.ShowPopup(popup);
        }
    }
}
```

the popup

```
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;

namespace MyPopupTest;

public partial class MyPopup : Popup
{
    public MyPopup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

This results in an exception: `The Parent must be of type Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.PageHandler.`

and the stack trace:

```
   at CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Views.MauiPopup.SetElement(IPopup element) in /_/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core/Views/Popup/MauiPopup.macios.cs:line 71
   at CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Handlers.PopupHandler.ConnectHandler(MauiPopup platformView) in /_/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core/Handlers/Popup/PopupHandler.macios.cs:line 91
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler`2[[CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.IPopup, CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Views.MauiPopup, CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].OnConnectHandler(Object platformView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.ConnectHandler(Object platformView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.PopupExtensions.CreatePopup(Page page, Popup popup) in /_/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui/Views/Popup/PopupExtensions.shared.cs:line 59
   at CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.PopupExtensions.ShowPopup[LayingTrackPopup](Page page, LayingTrackPopup popup) in /_/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui/Views/Popup/PopupExtensions.shared.cs:line 27
   at MyPopupTest.MyViewModel.DisplayLayingPopup() in /Users/…
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure You are following all steps? Like setting all paths in xaml, setting good references. I have recreated this task but was not able to get this error.

Working example:

Downloading from nuget CommunityToolkit.Maui (version 2.0.0), CommunityToolkit.Mvvm (version 8.0.0)

MauiProgram.cs

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            })
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MauiPopup"
         x:DataType="viewmodels:MainPageViewModel"
         x:Class="MauiPopup.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Command="{Binding ShowPopupCommand}"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
    }
}
```

MainPageViewModel.cs

```
internal class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ICommand ShowPopupCommand { get; }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        //ShowPopupCommand = new Command(ShowPopup);
        ShowPopup();
    }

    private void ShowPopup()
    {
        var popup = new PopupPage();
        Shell.Current.ShowPopup(popup);
    }
}
```

PopupPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mct:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:mct="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
         x:Class="MauiPopup.PopupPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Maui Popup!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</mct:Popup>
```

PopupPage.xaml

```
public partial class PopupPage : Popup
{
    public PopupPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with my view being TabbedPage implementation. If I move my code to a "normal" contentpage it works.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue following these specifications , any tips?